# ERROR - Inferred type is not general enough

Tags: function, haskell, types

I am trying to write a simple higher order function in Haskell which takes two arguments:

1. A list of functions of any type.
2. A list of (Numbers or `String`s or `Bool`ean, etc) --> any type

The function should apply all the functions in the first list to all the elements in the the second list, store the values in a list, and return the list. An example of the program is:

```
Main> apply [(^2),(^3),(^4)] [2..8]
--result: --[4,8,9,16,25,27,32,36,49,64,81,125,128,216,256,343,512,625,1296,2401,4096]
```

The type of the function must be:

```
apply :: Ord u => [v->u]->[v]->[u]
```

To do that I've used two helper functions and used recursion. My program is this:

```
apply :: Ord u => [v->u]->[v]->[u]             
apply p s = myApply p s []              --line 59--

myApply :: Ord u => [v->u]->[u]->[u]->[u]
myApply f_list num_list starterlist
    | null f_list = starterlist
    | otherwise = myApply (tail f_list) (num_list) ( applyList (head     f_list) num_list starterlist )

applyList :: Ord u => (v->u)->[u]->[u]->[u]
applyList f num_list starterlist
    | null num_list = starterlist
    | otherwise = applyList f (tail num_list) ( (head num_list) :     starterlist )
```

I get the error:

```
ERROR "Lab2.hs":59 - Inferred type is not general enough
*** Expression    : applyList
*** Expected type : Ord a => (b -> a) -> [a] -> [b] -> [a]
*** Inferred type : Ord a => (a -> a) -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]
```

Any idea what is wrong the with types?

Comment: Why should the type be `Ord u`?

Comment: The exercise says it must be ord u

Comment: but nowhere in your code you use some function that `Ord` is offering: you do not compare with `<`, `>`,...

Comment: Yeah i have to sort the values as well but that's something it doesn't concern me right now

Comment: Fwiw this is the Applicative instance for lists. You can use `<*>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why you get this error is because there are **conflicting type signatures**:

```
apply :: Ord u => [v->u]->[v]->[u]
apply p s = myApply p s []              --line 59--

myApply :: Ord u => [v->u]->[u]->[u]->[u]
myApply f_list num_list starterlist
    | null f_list = starterlist
    | otherwise = myApply (tail f_list) (num_list) ( applyList (head     f_list) num_list starterlist )
```

As you can see, the `apply` function immediately calls the `myApply` function. Since `myApply` has signature `[v -> u] -> [u] -> [u] -> [u]`, it means that `apply` can only have signature `[v->u] -> [u] -> [u]`.

A quick fix is to **generalize** both `myApply` and `myApplyList` to `[v -> u] -> [v] -> [u] -> [u]`. Now the compile will also detect an error you've made in your `applyList` function: you forgot to call `f` on the `head num_list`. So you can fix it and obtain the following code:

```
apply :: Ord u => [v->u]->[v]->[u]             
apply p s = myApply p s []              --line 59--

myApply :: Ord u => [v->u]->[v]->[u]->[u]
myApply f_list num_list starterlist
    | null f_list = starterlist
    | otherwise = myApply (tail f_list) (num_list) ( applyList (head     f_list) num_list starterlist )

applyList :: Ord u => (v->u)->[v]->[u]->[u]
applyList f num_list starterlist
    | null num_list = starterlist
    | otherwise = applyList f (tail num_list) ( (f (head num_list)) :     starterlist )
```

Nevertheless, this code is quite *unelegant* and uses way to many functions and arguments. You can replace it entirely with a single list comprehension:

```
apply :: [v -> u] -> [v] -> [u]
apply fs xs = [f x | f <- fs, x <- xs]
```

Based on your comment you also have to sort the values later in the process, you can do this by using the `sort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]` builtin:

```
-- sorting variant
apply :: Ord u => [v -> u] -> [v] -> [u]
apply fs xs = sort [f x | f <- fs, x <- xs]
```

This generates the required result:

```
Prelude Data.List> (\fs xs -> sort [f x | f <- fs, x <- xs]) [(^2),(^3),(^4)] [2..8]
[4,8,9,16,16,25,27,36,49,64,64,81,125,216,256,343,512,625,1296,2401,4096]
```

Answer (score 4):

Variation on a theme: taking into Willem's comment indicating that this is a pretty convoluted code (making it difficult to analyze) I'd start with a simpler code, without stating any types at all, to first get a simple working case (that is, a function that produces the expected output), still using a helper function, and recursion:

```
apply fs     []  = []
apply []     xs  = []
apply (f:fs) xs  = (helper f xs) ++ (apply fs xs)

helper f []     = []
helper f (x:xs) = f x : helper f xs
```

Then I would ask the Haskell compiler to give me information about what type signature it inferred:

```
*Main> :t apply
apply :: [t1 -> t] -> [t1] -> [t]
```

By realizing that `t1 -> t` maps to your `v->u`, I can see that the type signature can also be written as:

```
[v -> u] -> [v] -> [u]
```

Doing the similar for `helper`, you will end up with the following:

```
apply :: [v->u] -> [v] -> [u]             
apply fs     []  = []
apply []     xs  = []
apply (f:fs) xs  = (helper f xs) ++ (apply fs xs)

helper :: (v -> u) -> [v] -> [u]
helper f []     = []
helper f (x:xs) = f x : helper f xs
```

From here, you can work your way by adding `Ord` constraint, and build up sorting functionality, etc.